# String Newline not displaying in Doors

Tags: ibm-doors

I have csv file containing some data like:

```
374,Test Comment multiplelines \n Here's the 2nd line,Other_Data
```

Where 374 is the object ID from doors, then some commentary and then some other data. 
I have a piece of code that reads the data from the CSV file, stores it in the appropriate variables and then writes it to the doors Object.

```
Module Openend_module = edit("path_to_mod", true,true,true)
Object o ;
Column c;
string attrib;
string oneLine ;
string OBJECT_ID = "";
string Comment = "";
String Other_data = "";

int offset;

string split_text(string s)
{
        if (findPlainText(s, sub, offset, len, false)) 
        {
            return s[0 : offset -1]   
        } 
        else 
        {
            return ""
        }
}

Stream input = read("Path_to_Input.txt");
input >> oneLine
OBJECT_ID = split_text(oneLine)
oneLine = oneLine[offset+1:]
Comment = split_text(oneLine)
Other_data = oneLine[offset+1:]
```

When using `print Comment` the output in the DXL console is : `Test Comment multiplelines \n Here's the 2nd line`

```
for o in Opened_Module do 
{
if (o."Absolute Number"""==OBJECT_ID ){
   attrib = "Result_Comment " 2
   o.attrib = Comment
  }
}
```

But after writing to the doors object, the `\n` is not taken into consideration and the result is as follows:

[image]

I've tried putting the string inside a Buffer and using `stringOf()` but the escape character just disappeared.
I've also tried adding `\r\n` and `\\n` to the input csv text but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most efficient way of handling this, but I have a relatively straightforward fix.

I would suggest adding the following:

```
Module Openend_module = edit("path_to_mod", true,true,true)
Object o ;
Column c;
string attrib;
string oneLine ;
string OBJECT_ID = "";
string Comment = "";
String Other_data = "";

int offset;

string split_text(string s)
{
        if (findPlainText(s, sub, offset, len, false)) 
        {
            return s[0 : offset -1]   
        } 
        else 
        {
            return ""
        }
}

Stream input = read("Path_to_Input.txt");
input >> oneLine
OBJECT_ID = split_text(oneLine)
oneLine = oneLine[offset+1:]
Comment = split_text(oneLine)
Other_data = oneLine[offset+1:]

//Modification to comment string
int x
int y
while ( findPlainText ( Comment , "\\n" , x , y , false ) ) {
     Comment = ( Comment [ 0 : x - 1 ] ) "\n" ( Comment [ x + 2 : ] )
}
```

This will run the comment string through a parser, replacing string "\n" with the char '\n'. Be aware- this will ignore any trailing spaces at the end of a line.

Let me know if that helps.